# Working with jagged arrays, printing sub-array to sheet, vba

Tags: excel, vba

**Background:**

Was trying to come up with efficient ways to handle a large amount of tables on a single sheet and came across *Jagged Arrays* (herein "**Jar**s").

To simply understand some basics of Jars, I was trying to build a simple scenario of staggered information to be able to create the Jar.

My Jar is labeled `big_arr` and each array inside is called `lil_arr`.

Here is the data for the scenario:

```
   ColA 'adding row number in front of each word
1  cat
2  dog
3
4  mouse
5  elephant
6
7  zebra
8  snake
9
10 cheese
11 pickle
12
13 anteater
14 mirkat
15
16 skunk
17 smurf
```

In the above scenario, `big_arr(2) = lil_arr` where `lil_arr = array("mouse","elephant").

I would then have `big_arr(i)` print to a sheet; the sheet is labeled as `i`, when looping.  So sheet `2` would have `cells(1,1).value = "mouse"` and `cells(1,2).value = "elephant"`.

---

**Issue:**

I am having issues getting the data to print as expected.

The exact printing that is happening (based on `i` as the sheet name):

- 1 has `cells(1,1).value = 0`
- 2 has `cells(1,1).value = "skunk"`
- 3 has `cells(1,1).value = 0`
- 4 has `cells(1,1).value = 0`
- 5 has `cells(1,1).value = 0`
- 6 has `cells(1,1).value = 0`

I don't seem to be able to print using `Application.Transpose(big_arr(i))`.  I have attempted to loop, but don't seem to have appropriate syntax.

---

**Question:**

Any help to resolve the issue with `Application.Transpose()`, which does not trigger an error message, would be appreciated.

Otherwise, help to get the loop to work with appropriate syntax would be phenomenal.

---

**Code in question:**

Code with `Application.Transpose()` for printing

```
Sub create_jagged_array_of_tables()
    Dim big_arr As Variant, lil_arr As Variant, lr As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, ws As Worksheet
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim big_arr(1 To lr)
    For i = 1 To lr
        j = 1
        Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i + j, 1))
            j = j + 1
        Loop
        If j > 1 Then
            lil_arr = Cells(i, 1).Resize(j).Value
            big_arr(j) = lil_arr
            i = i + j
            k = k + 1
        Else
            MsgBox "row " & i & " is not part of an array"
        End If
    Next i
    For i = 1 To k
        Set ws = Sheets.Add
        ws.Name = i
        Cells(1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(big_arr(i))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Code for the loop I attempted, giving type-mismatch, focusing only on the `for i = 1 to k` loop:

```
    For i = 1 To k
        Set ws = Sheets.Add
        ws.Name = i
        'Cells(1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(big_arr(i))
        For j = 1 To UBound(big_arr(i), 1)
            Cells(j, 1).Value = big_arr(i)(j)
        Next j
    Next i
```

Comment: When you're loading the data in to the `big_arr`, where's the data coming from? Do you have `cat` in `A1`, then `dog` in `A2`, and `mouse` in `A3`, etc?

Comment: @BruceWayne A1 = Cat, A2 = Dog, A4 = Mouse, etc.  Will update the data I used for the Scenario to show row numbers.  Sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case `j` will always = `2` at the line:

> `big_arr(j) = lil_arr`

so you keep overwriting that.

I assume you want to use k instead of j for the counter of big_arr:

> `big_arr(k) = lil_arr`

But that will require you to have a k=1 before the i loop.

Also you need to resize the output to the size of the lil_array:

```
Sub create_jagged_array_of_tables()
    Dim big_arr As Variant, lil_arr As Variant, lr As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, ws As Worksheet
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim big_arr(1 To lr)
    k = 0
    For i = 1 To lr
        j = 1
        Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i + j, 1))
            j = j + 1
        Loop
        If j > 1 Then
            lil_arr = Cells(i, 1).Resize(j).Value
            k = k + 1
            big_arr(k) = lil_arr
            i = i + j                
        Else
            MsgBox "row " & i & " is not part of an array"
        End If
    Next i

    For i = 1 To k
        Set ws = Sheets.Add
        ws.Name = i
        Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(big_arr(i), 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(big_arr(i))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `k` should be the count for the number of `lil_arr` within `big_arr`.  I should go back and annotate since i didn't use fully-named variables.  I did that as I have dimensioned `big_arr(1 to lr)` where lr in this example is 17, but I have 6 `lil_arr` within `big_arr`.  I will try to resize as you've listed.

Comment: @Cyril it works as is.  Only 6 sheets created and no errors.  It pastes the values from each array horizontally in row 1.

Comment: @Cyril I fixed it so that now k will equal the number of arrays in Big_array.

Comment: Thank you for that; apparently my two-fold issue was as you've listed, that I had incorrectly appended `lil_arr` to `big_arr(j)` instead of `big_arr(k)`, then the resize did the trick.  I think the j/k issue could have been resolved had I either annotated or used appropriately named variables (comment I had above).  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Did just a little tweaking and it's working for me:

```
Sub create_jagged_array_of_tables()
    Dim big_arr As Variant, lil_arr As Variant, lr As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, ws As Worksheet
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim big_arr_size As Long

    ' Assumes you have groups of 2 per small array
    big_arr_size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1:A" & lr)) / 2
    ReDim big_arr(1 To big_arr_size)
    k = 1
    For i = 1 To lr
        j = 1
        Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i + j, 1))
            j = j + 1
        Loop
        If j > 1 Then
            lil_arr = Cells(i, 1).Resize(j).Value
            big_arr(k) = lil_arr ' changed `j` to `k`
            i = i + j
            k = k + 1
        Else
            MsgBox "row " & i & " is not part of an array"
        End If
    Next i
    For i = 1 To big_arr_size
        Set ws = Sheets.Add
        ws.Name = i
        ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = big_arr(i)(1, 1)
        ws.Cells(1, 2).Value = big_arr(i)(2, 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Edit:  Here's a perhaps different way you can do this. It avoids using a "small array" to set as part of a larger array.

```
Sub t()
Dim big_arr As Variant

Dim lr As Long
lr = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim big_arr_size As Long

' Assumes you have groups of 2 per small array
big_arr_size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1:A" & lr)) / 2
ReDim big_arr(1 To lr)
big_arr = Range("A1:A" & lr).Value

Dim i As Long, wsName As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
wsName = LBound(big_arr)
For i = LBound(big_arr) To UBound(big_arr) - 1
    If Not IsEmpty(big_arr(i, 1)) And Not IsEmpty(big_arr(i + 1, 1)) Then
        Set ws = Sheets.Add
        ws.Name = wsName
        ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = big_arr(i, 1)
        ws.Cells(1, 2).Value = big_arr(i + 1, 1)
        wsName = wsName + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You and Scott both hit on my issue with `j` & `k`, which I should have given better names (i threw in `k` last second to count and forgot to update in apparently an additional location).  I threw the Answered mark to Scott as he hit on helping with resize as in the future these small arrays will not consistently be 2-long (i just happened to have that for my first example which in hindsight seems inappropriate/misleading).  Your edit is more aligned with my standard array practice... grab it all and check the array for what will happen, rather than focusing on Jars.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

The Post already had two brilliant answers (one accepted) and both have there unique characteristics. But just want to share some of my idea since I find the the post highly interesting. I just tried to simplify the creation of jagged array using single loop using a flag and avoided transpose. May please not taken as  contravention.

```
Sub create_jagged_array_of_tables()
    Dim big_arr() As Variant, lil_arr As Variant, lr As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Dim Nw As Boolean, Xval As Variant
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    k = 0
    j = 0
    For i = 1 To lr
    Xval = Cells(i, 1).Value
        If IsEmpty(Xval) = False Then
            If Nw = False Then
            Nw = True
            k = k + 1
            j = 1
            ReDim lil_arr(1 To 1, 1 To j)
            lil_arr(1, j) = Xval
            ReDim Preserve big_arr(1 To k)
            big_arr(k) = lil_arr
            Else
            j = j + 1
            ReDim Preserve lil_arr(1 To 1, 1 To j)
            lil_arr(1, j) = Xval
            big_arr(k) = lil_arr
            End If
        Else
        Nw = False
        End If
    Next i

    For i = 1 To k
        Set ws = Sheets.Add
        ws.Name = i
        Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(big_arr(i), 2)).Value = big_arr(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

And if creation of jagged Array is not required and sole objective is to copy the content in the desired fashion, the it could be further simplified to

```
Sub test1()
Dim lr As Long, Rng As Range, Area As Range, Cnt As Long, Arr As Variant
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = Range("A1:A" & lr)
Rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
Set Rng = Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
 Cnt = 0
 For Each Area In Rng.Areas
 Cnt = Cnt + 1
 Set ws = Sheets.Add
 ws.Name = Cnt
 Arr = Area.Value
    If IsArray(Arr) Then
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(Arr, 2), UBound(Arr, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)
    Else
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = Arr
    End If
 Next
Rng.AutoFilter Field:=1
End Sub
```